selenium java wait for page to load completely
Application under test do have its own loading bar so when a element is clicked from main page while applications loading bar is not complete a new page opens but upon application loading loading bar completion it navigates me back to main page.
I tried:
1- Page loading strategy as Normal via chrome Options library.
2-
Boolean ready=  js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
   if(ready){
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@mattooltip='Rules']//span[1]"))).click();
       System.out.println(ready);
   }
   else {
       Thread.sleep(10000);
   }

Boolean value returns true however, Application own loading bar does not loads completely yet and page reloads back to main page.I want loading bar to complete and then click element or if application navigates to next page it should not move back to previous page and do the next actions.
Note: Loading bar disappears after loading i am unable to locate loader element.

Just use an explicit webdriverwait with expectedconditions to wait for the item you want to interact with first.  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

That has already been used in IF condition. Let me clear there are three things one is web browser loading other is application loader and there is only one element that i click from main page. Browser and application loader starts at same time, Browser loading completes first and selenium clicks element and navigate to next page. however, application loader is still loading. Now application loader completes and it brings me to main page which it shouldn't. I want it to wait for the application loader to complete and than click elm. For now it is checking browser loading and click element.

You can try and target the loading/progress indicator and use webdriverwait with expected condition of invisibilityOfElement, or get that element first and check for stalenessOf(progress_element)  If this is an embed, you'll probably need to use a sleep that would cover the timing there.
